# pause de 2 segundo ao enviar email

Tags: php, dompdf

A pergunta duplicada mostrou como enviar e nao ser identificado como spam..agora gostaria de fazer um sleep entre envios ...

Utilizo o swiftmailer para enviar emails e gostava de ter um atrazo no envio de 2 segundo por email enviado.. ja tentei utilizar o sleep(2); no loop assim:

```
foreach($users as $user) {sleep(2);
  $message->setTo($user["email"], $user["nome"]);
  $mailer->send($message);
```

mas nao resulta... o envio é processado todo de uma so vez depois de 2 segundo e devia de ser 2 segundos por email...alguma ideia ? obg
";

```
// Create the mail transport configuration
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("xxx.xxx.com", 25);
$transport->setUsername("xxx");
$transport->setPassword("xxx");


// Usually you want to replace the following static array
// with a dynamic one built retrieving users from the database
$users = unserialize($_POST['result']);





// Create the replacements array
$replacements = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $replacements[$user["email"]] = array (
    "{nome}" => $user["nome"],
    "{total}" => $user["total"]
  );

}

// Create the mail transport configuration
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create an instance of the plugin and register it
$plugin = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($replacements);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->registerPlugin($plugin);

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject("Pedido de recibos TopHospedeiras");
//$message->setCc('recibos@tophospedeiras.com');


// $message->setBody("msg a enviar

");


$message->setFrom("wallet@topfarmamkt.com", "Tophospedeiras");
// Send the email
foreach($users as $user) {
  $message->setTo($user["email"], $user["nome"]);
  $mailer->send($message);




  $ne++;
  echo "</br>n:".$ne."&nbsp".$user["email"]."</br> >>enviado</br>";

}
```

Comment: onde você esta definindo o sleep?

Comment: tentei dentro do loop : foreach($users as $user) { sleep(2); mas n deu

Comment: É... estranho isso, pois o sleep é a função que executa o que você está querendo mesmo, o correto seria colocar o sleep antes do `$mailer->send($message);`, teste usando a função em microsegundos `usleep(2000000);`.

Comment: tambem nao deu ..fica pausado

Comment: De um `echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";` antes de `$mailer->send($message)`, após ele dê o `sleep(2)`, e após o sleep de mais um `echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";`, compare os horários e veja se pausou... Essa função não tem segredo, não teria um porque não funcionar kkk

Comment: acho que sim que resultou, so nao esta a mostrar o echo um a um

Comment: quando termina ele mostra que pausou mas mostrou tudo junto no fim

Comment: Ou usa o cron para mandar um email a cada X minutos.

Comment: @I-amSam, ele mostra tudo junto porque a menos que você diga o contrário, a saída do PHP será feita somente depois que todo script for processado. Isso não significa que o sleep não está funcionando. Resumindo: os e-mails estão sendo enviados com o intervalo de 2 segundos do sleep, porém, o echo será exibido de uma única vez.